# How do i control CSSclass in Sitecore Master Layout

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sitecore

I have a Master layout in Sitecore that is used for all of the pages. The master layout has some dynamic features ... for instance, the code below represents the Markup for a tab at the top of the page... this tab is either active or in active ...

```
<div class="main-nav>
   <a id="tabmovies" href="/Movies" class="main-nav-tab active">Movies</a>
   <a id="tabtheatres" href="/Theatres" class="main-nav-tab">Theatres</a> 
</div>
```

Everytime a page loads, this is the Markup ... Movies are active. I want to control whether the person has clicked on tabmovies or tabtheatres and toggle the "active" part of the CSSclass

Is there anything I can do to make this work? a session variable, note this is all "client-side" to make this even more complicated.

the only easy solution is to have two master layouts and depending on what the user has selected, use either one of those.

that may be my only option.

Comment: Are you using any JS libraries like jQuery or raw JavaScript?

Comment: both Javascript and jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend generating the navigation and setting the class appropriately depending on whatever logic you need.  Bind the collection of navigation items to the repeater

```
<asp:Repeater id="rptMainNav" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptMainNav_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <div class="main-nav">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </div>
    </FooterTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink id="NavItemLink" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then on item data bound you can set the css classes appropriately.

```
protected void rptMainNav_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {
        Sitecore.Data.Items.Item navItem = (Sitecore.Data.Items.Item)e.Item.DataItem;
        HyperLink navLink = e.Item.FindControl("NavItemLink");

        navLink.Text = navItem.DisplayName;
        navLink.NavigateUrl = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(navItem);
        navLink.Attributes["class"] = "main-nav-tab";

        // This is where you would put whatever check you want...
        //  - For example if the page is the current page
        //  - Or if the nav item is an ancestor of the current page
        if(Sitecore.Context.Item.Id == navItem.Id) {
            navLink.Attributes["class"] += " active";
        }

        // set more link attributes, etc.
    }
}
```

This is a pretty normal way for setting active state on navigation elements and allowing it to be dynamic.  I would strongly recommend against hard-coding navigation links and text into your global layout.  Let it be a TreelistEx collection of items on the Homepage or site root for example.  Have fun Sitecore-ing it up.

Comment: This is what I would do too. The key to the whole solution is checking if the current page (context item) is the item you're on in your loop: `Sitecore.Context.Item.Id == navItem.Id`